# Ternary statement not accepted in JSX (Unexpected token "?")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

using a ternary statement to render different JSX depending on `shouldRenderPlanA` property (which resolves true or false). Issue however is that an error appears at the `shouldRenderPlanA` ternary check with the following:

"Unexpected token `?`, expected the token `:`"

Can anyone explain where I might be going wrong? TIA

```
    return (
      <>
        {options.map(option)}
        <StyledRow>
          {variousOptions.map((opt) => (
            {shouldRenderPlanA ? (            
              <StyledLabelOptionOne
                 variousProps={variousProps}
              />
              ) : (            
              <StyledLabelOptionTwo
                 variousProps={variousProps}
              />
            )}
          ))}
        </StyledRow>
      </>
    );
```

My suspicion is that it's something to do with the check happening inside the map?

Comment: It's because you've used braces when you were _already in a JS context_. You're writing an arrow function returning an object, in which case following the key name by `?` makes no sense.

Comment: You are trying to use JSX syntax outside of JSX. Everything between `=> (` and `<StyledLabelOptionOne` is normal javascript. So you need to replace `{` with `return`

Comment: wrap it in a new element

Comment: The unexpected token `?` error is because js (not jsx) thinks you are trying to declare an object literal. It is expecting `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use nested braces `{}` in JSX, remove the inner ones and it will work:

```js
  return (
    <>
      {options.map(option)}
      <StyledRow>
        {variousOptions.map((opt) => shouldRenderPlanA ? (
          <StyledLabelOptionOne
            variousProps={variousProps}
          />
        ) : (
          <StyledLabelOptionTwo
            variousProps={variousProps}
          />
        ))}
      </StyledRow>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem.

```
          (
            {shouldRenderPlanA ? (
```

You can't expect to return an object, instead

```
  (shouldRenderPlanA ?
```

Or try to write something simple at the beginning , ex. `flag?1:0` to get it working before plugging other things :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because you didn't return a value inside the map

Maybe this can help you

```
return (
  <>
    {options.map(option)}
    <StyledRow>
      {variousOptions.map((opt) => {
        return shouldRenderPlanA ? (            
          <StyledLabelOptionOne
             variousProps={variousProps}
          />
          ) : (            
          <StyledLabelOptionTwo
             variousProps={variousProps}
          />
        }
      ))}
    </StyledRow>
  </>
);
```

You muset remove the parentheses, and return the element